# Sanitize YAML front matter content with yq (macOS)

Tags: python, yaml, yq

I have around 30,000 .md files which include a frontmatter.
all of them have different set of keys. To sort them alphabetically I successfully used brew yq and find.

```sh
find ./ -type f -name "*.md" -exec yq -i -f process 'sort_keys(.)' "{}" \;
```

Now I need to sanitize tags, which have one of the next three forms

```yaml
---
author: Karen the Trollmaster
tags: [legal, business, security]
tags: legal, business, security
tags: legal,business/entrepreneurship security
---
```

I need to sort them alphabetically, and convert them from string to a proper array

```
tags: [business/entrepreneurship, legal, security]
```

I tried

```sh
yq '.tags | sub("," , " ") | split(" ")' something.md
```

and

```sh
yq '.tags | sub("," , " ") | map(split(" "))' something.md
```

but all i'm getting is an empty array, or an error saying can't substitute with !!null

The desired output would be as an array without ""

```yaml
tags: [business/entrepreneurship, legal, security, watermelons]
```

Comment: Exactly, tags can take any of those three forms, It all depends on how the frontmatter was generated.

Comment: How is this valid `tags: legal,business/entrepreneurship security`? the `security` is not separated by comma here? the mandatory delimiter character should be present isn't it?

Comment: it's not valid YAML, it's just a string, some of those tags were manually added, some articles were clipped with a lot of different clippers, some were from evernote exported using yarle, others come from bear, quiver, onenote, some were generated with bash sed. Now that I discovered yq I would love to sanitize those files and give them a consistent form.

Comment: yq has features, but not enough to satisfy all 3 cases, for e.g. for a valid case (1st example) you have no way to know the the list is sorted and perform no action

Comment: I can run different command per case, but how do I switch from per line - indented syntax to bracket [] syntax ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242397/discussion-between-aalvarado-and-inian).

Comment: See my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the [`--front-matter=process`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/#notice-for-v4.x-versions-prior-to-4.18.1) when modifying the front-matter content and pass the required expression to modify the tags.

For case 1) pre-formatted array notation with just sorting needed, use yq as

```
yq e -f process '.tags |= sort' yaml
```

For case 2) splitting needed on `,`  do it as below. The `flow` style puts the array contents within the `[..]`

```
yq e -f process '.tags |= (split(", ") | sort | . style="flow") ' yaml
```

For case 3) it is not clear if the input is valid as the mandatory delimiter `,` is not present as part of one the inputs. Use the solution for case 2 as applicable.

Note: If you are using yq version 4.18.1 or beyond, [the eval flag `e` is no longer needed](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/#notice-for-v4.x-versions-prior-to-4.18.1) as it has been made the default action.

Comment: Your answer solved my problem, thank you very much. the only problem is I've found another case tags: [legal business security], this sort of solves it `yq -f process '.tags |= map(split(" "))' test.md` but now its an array inside an array [[legal, business, security]].